# Azure Pipeline build error Npm failed with return code: 4294963238

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am getting NPM error when I am trying to build the solution as follows

```
144812 error Windows_NT 10.0.17763 
144813 error argv "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\6.17.1\\x64\\node.exe"    "C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\node\\6.17.1\\x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" 
144814 error node v6.17.1 
144815 error npm v3.10.10 
144816 error path D:\a\45\s\Presentation Tier\VendorPortal.Web.UI\node_modules\.staging\@types\node-b1eb4de5\package.json 
144817 error code ENOTDIR 
144818 error errno -4058 
144819 error syscall open 
144820 error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\45\s\Presentation  Tier\VendorPortal.Web.UI\node_modules\.staging\@types\node-b1eb4de5\package.json' 
144821 error If you need help, you may report this error at: 
144821 error <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues> 
144822 verbose exit [ -4058, true ] 
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 4294963238
```

I tried delete package-lock.json, npm cache clean command, npm install npm@latest -g everything. But I am still getting the error. Error occurs in NPM install step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npm failed with return code: 4294963238, in CI in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227020/npm-failed-with-return-code-4294963238-in-ci-in-vsts)

Comment: nop I tried this as well